# Unity Object is already destroyed just after the fetch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a loop to search for a specific object from a list so then I store it in a global variable. But when I try to fetch it's always null and the game crashes.

```
SpecialItem pickedItem; // (global variable)

void OnGUI()
{
    for loop (all objects) // Idictionary<SpecialItem, string>
    {
        pickedItem = Instantiate(myItem) as SpecialItem;
        Debug.Log("this->" + pickedItem.name.ToString());  // ERROR
    }

}
```

> Unity error is: MissingReferenceException: The object of type
>   'SpecialItem' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access
>   it.

i thought it was because of the foreach so I've replace it by a normal for loop

can someone explain me why this happens? and what can be done to be fix? my original idea was to work with the object itself, but it seems I couldn't so I tried make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the code I've submitted to stackoverflow itself.

I have a physical object to which I attach the SpecialItem script. When I pick it to the inventory I was using Destroy(gameObject).

For some weird reason I was still able to access some of it's variables like 'Texture', 'ammount' or 'slots'. But once I tried to access 'name' it crashed because the object was already destroyed.

so I've replaced the:

Destroy(gameObject);

for

gameObject.SetActive(false);

and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the object is of type SpecialItem?

the "as" keyword will return null if the object can not be cast to the type.

What is the signature for Instantiate(myItem)?

Comment: I've tried to debug just after pickedItem = and i got the same problem... Is there a difference between using as SpecialItem and (SpecialItem) cast? I'm pretty sure the object is from that type since the  dictionary itself is from SpecialItem

Comment: The difference is that (SpecialItem) cast will throw an Exception where "as" will just assign the object to null.

Comment: just as I do this on entry of the loop myItem = list[i]; next line seems its already null but after that i can use properties like myItem.ammount.toString() I think im not initializing the object correctly. How am I suppose to do a correct initialization?

Comment: sorry I'm new on unity isn't Instance a native function? You are asking for its Start() ?

Comment: I think the problem might just that I'm trying to fetch a physical object which i destroy on fetch for inventory... So once i try to pick it in the inventory its already destroyed, but for some reason I'm still able to use its properties. Maybe I should be disabling it ?

Comment: fix it thanks the problem was I was destroying the object itself instead using gameObject.setActive(false); if you change your answer i'll accept it. Thank you very much for clearing my mind.

Comment: I'm confused, Unity is an IOC container (think very smart factory). Are you using Entity Framework? The code above will not compile because you left out the loop logic, Can you update it to the actual code that you have? Including the using statements? Are you using Unity3d?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25892/discussion-between-navy-seal-and-jras)